# How can I calculate to how fast heat is transferred from the surface of a massive hall to the ceiling?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, climate-science

I have asked something similar to this question before but couldn't get an useful answer: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/213240/i-am-building-an-isolated-indoor-temperate-rain-forest-what-will-the-temperatur

TLDR. I am writing a story. In the story I want to build a forest in a closed system. (energy transfer allowed.) I would like to describe how it looks and what systems are running the building. For this I need to be able to calculate how fast heat is transferred from the forest floor to the ceiling.

The values I am currently working with:
Forest is built in 8 self similar triangular segments. Each of these is $5km$ long $3.6km$ wide and thus has a surface area of $9km^2$. The ceiling and walls are a perfect reflector. The ceiling is cooled to $4°C$ and is $0.6km$ above the floor. (one may imagine this ceiling to be polished solid steel. cooled by water of $4°C$ running through channels that are carved into the material. therefore it can be assumed to be $4°C$ at all times for the ease of calculation.) Lighting in the ceiling provides $9GW$ of power/light for 12 hours a day(24h). The air the structure was filled with was pressurised to $1atm=1.013*10^5$Pa at $20°C$

[image: hall schematic]

I have found the ideal gas law. $$PV=nRT$$ When trying stuff out I just assumed the forest would get up to $14°C$ from there I could get a pressure difference of $34.56Pa$. $$(P1/T1)*T2=P2$$ $$P(4°C)=(1.013*10^5/293,15)*277,15=0.9577*10^5Pa$$ $$P(14°C)=(1.013*10^5/293,15)*287,15=0.9923*10^5Pa$$ $$dP=0.9923*10^5-0.9577*10^5=0.0346*10^5Pa=3460Pa$$ And I also managed to get an density difference of $44g/m^3$. $$Mass=P*V*molarmass/R*T $$ $$Mass(1m^3)(20°C)=(1.013*10^5*1*28.97)/(293,15*8,31)=1205g$$ $$(V1/T1)*T2=V2$$ $$V(4°C)=(1/293,15)*277,15=0,9454m^3$$ $$V(14°C)=(1/293,15)*287,15=0,9795m^3$$ $$Density=Mass/V$$ $$dDensity=(1205/0,9454)-(1205/0,9795)=44g/m^3$$

Lastly I looked up a specific heat capacity of $0.00121J/cm^3*K=1.21kJ/m^3*K$

From here I am stuck. How can I calculate to how fast heat is transferred from the surface to the ceiling?

Comment: Can you show a picture of your forest in 3D with  length and width?

Comment: Is the ceiling maintained at a constant temperature of $4^0 C$? And by a completely reflective surface do you mean one that reflects thermal radiation or it is also meant to have insulative properties?

Comment: @user7896 yes the ceiling surface is maintained at $4^oC$. the only energy entering the system is from the light. all of that energy is absorbed by the forest and nowhere else. energy can only leave the system at the ceilings surface which is kept at $4^oC$ (the problem is hard enough as it is. no need to complicate things more by having the walls participate in energy exchange)